# How to get the id of the div where I drop an element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-droppable

Let's make it useful with this link: [conta.md/rafturi/kae/tester.php](http://conta.md/rafturi/kae/tester.php).

I have 2 `div`s (containers), one `div` clone draggable white background and one black `div` draggable that comes from mysql (let's say).

I want that when I move the black div from the curent `div` parent to the next one to have a variable insite `stop:function` that give me de id of the new div. Please show me what exactly to do. inside this `stop:function` I have 2 variables: one gives me the id of the current `div` and ones give me de id of the element I move (black `div`).

Answer (score 4):

To get the id of the dropped location where my li has an id value set so

```
<li id="12">---</li>

$("#sortable li").droppable({
      hoverClass: 'droparea',
       drop: 
            function( event, ui ) {
                droppedId = $( this ).attr("id");
                alert (droppedId);
            }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$(element).draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) { dropElementID = $(ui.droppable).attr('id'); }   
});
```